# Is there a definitive guide for special folders in windows?

Tags: windows, special-folders, known-folders

Is there a definitive guide for special folders in windows? An internet search yielded just a few crumbs of information, e.g.

- [Wikipedia:Special Folders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Folders)
- [Windows 7 Client Software Logo Program](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=27028822-b172-4cec-91a3-26b610a4da79)

What I'm looking for is an explanation of each folder, its intended purpose, usage scenarios and motivation for its existence (e.g. what does Local App settings provide for that App settings doesn't). A matrix/table of requirements/uses against folder would be handy I think.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556082/as-a-developer-how-should-i-use-the-special-folders-in-vista-and-windows-7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the `CSILD` reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

and the `KNOWNFOLDERID` reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the CSILD and KNOWNFOLDERID references, you can find also some useful bits [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310294/en) (*Classify Application Data* and following).