# Specifying c:\ProgramData folder in Setup project?

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project

I am using a Windows Installer deployment project in VS 2010 to create an installer for a small demo project. The demo needs to install a SQL Compact database file (MyData.sdf). The demo can't install the database to the application folder on the user's machine--I get an "access denied" error if I do that. So, the logical place to install the database would seem to be a subfolder under the user's c:\ProgramData folder.

How do I specify the c:\ProgramData folder in the deployment project's File System Editor? I right-click the *File System on Target Machine* node and hover over *Add Special Folder* to see the fly-out list of special folders, but I don't see a special folder that looks like it corresponds to the c:\ProgramData folder.

Does one of the entries on the list correspond to the folder? Do I have to set it up as a custom folder? If I do, how would I set up the custom folder? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I don't think it's available in the fly-out. You can create Custom Folder and set its `DefaultLocation` property to `[CommonAppDataFolder]`.

Comment: Also, this question I asked a while back may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215471/locating-installer-paths-in-c

Comment: Here's the MSDN page describing this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/716bxh4e(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @kjbartel your link is dead.

Comment: @spender I am using Visual Studio 2017 for an installer and I can't see [CommonAppDataFolder] in DefaultLocation option. What would be the equivalent option in Visual Studio 2017 installer?

Comment: I created a custom folder (like what spender suggests) and manually typed `[CommonAppDataFolder]` in the `DefaultLocation` area. I'm using VS 2019, if that matters.

Comment: Thank and don't forget to set AlwaysCreate to true for the subfolder