# Visual Studio Setup Project install files to ProgramData with read-write permissions

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, setup-project

I am trying to include a file that with my Windows Forms application that be read-write for all users. I was able get the Setup Project to install files to the ProgramData folder using a  custom folder with DefaultLocation property set to [CommonAppDataFolder]. I was also able to get my program to read these files using Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) . But the files are all marked as read-only for Users.

Is there another folder I should be installing these files to that will offer common access to all users with read-write permissions?

I found a few threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760/vs2008-setup-project-shared-by-all-users-application-data-files), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729010/specifying-c-programdata-folder-in-setup-project),  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288444/how-to-give-read-write-permissions-to-a-folder-during-installation-using-net). But they don't answer the question which folder should I be using to get read-write common access for all users.

Any thoughts appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a subfolder in the CommonApplicationData folder, and **setting permissions during installation** is correct and is the [Microsoft "One True Way"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitava/archive/2007/07/16/certified-for-windows-vista-logo-test-case-faq-test-case-15.aspx):

> **Question:** Where to store read/write data for all users?
>
> **Answer:** The suggestion for you is to use the ProgramData (%ALLUSERSPROFILE%)
>   folder (e.g, create ProgramData\\) and **update the
>   Access Control List (ACL) according to your requirement**, during
>   install. The MSDN resource Per-machine Installations at
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370810.aspx should be
>   helpful to you.

This is because some applications may legitimately not want regular users to have write access to the folder, perhaps only to allow a service account to write to the central location.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.